# Request for circuit review: varactor-tuned AM radio receiver

Tags: operational-amplifier, radio, amplitude-modulation, varactor

I apologize if this is not the place for newbie questions or circuit review requests, but I was hoping for some wisdom on an AM receiver circuit I have sketched out.

From left to right it is intended to read as tuner/demodulator/amplifier. Actual component values aside, is there anything that jumps out as woefully incorrect in terms of how the circuit is structured?

Varactor-tuned AM receiver and amplifier:

[image]

Comment: I don't have much experience with designing radio receivers, but I can't imagine it being a good idea to connect a battery straight to the antenna.

Comment: What value is R1? It has to be approximately 0 or your tuned circuit has very low q and no useful selectivity.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny good point... thanks!

Comment: @user_1818839 value of r1 TBD. the intent was to form a voltage divider network in order to bias the varactor. What would be the correct implimentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic block functions (tuner, demodulator, amplifier) are reasonable, and in correct order.
However, each has its own problems:

- Tuner varactor should be biased so that resonator Q remains high.
- Tuner EARTH is not shown.
- Demodulator diode (D2 shown below) often has no DC bias.
- Audio amplifier should not be DC coupled from the demodulator in an AM radio.
- OPamp might benefit from a negative as well as positive DC supply, since its audio inputs and output is ground-referenced.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFat51.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A single DC power supply is possible, but requires extra components.

C3 and R3 are needed so that the demodulator stage does not pass on its DC output voltage to the high-gain audio opamp. This simple diode (D2, C2, R2) demodulator generates a DC output voltage proportional to AM carrier amplitude, with audio riding along...you want the audio, but not the DC.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough response, definitely made a few things click for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but a comment is the wrong place for a schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw8gYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 must be a high value to reduce damping on the tuned circuit. R2 supplies a variable tuning voltage.

L1 is chosen to resonate with (D2 and C1 in series) with D2 at maximum capacitance (lowest voltage) at 530kHz (bottom of the AM band).

D2 ... going to be difficult to find varicaps up to the 300-500pF range nowadays, I haven't seen them for a couple of decades.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: Any diode is  a varicap , which increases C with current rating, but 1uH @ 1MHz is in the 8 ohm range needs to be increased by at least 100x to 1000x with ferrite rod  then R increase to > 1M and C reduces to a few hundred pF or less. C is max at 0V then declines with log V. No added series R as this reduces Q with load R = 100x Xc-Xl then Q= 10 kHz

Comment: Any diode is a varicap, but precious few exceed 10-20pF.  And sizng L to resonate with (say) 15pF will make L infeasibly large, with a series R that kills Q again. (I didn't mean to leave its default value in the schematic - sorry, 1uF isn't enough) Just about any book or article on crystal set design will set you right on a reasonably optimal L.

Answer (score 0):

Any diode is  a varicap , which increases C with current rating, but 1uH @ 1MHz is in the 8 ohm range needs to be increased by at least 100x to 1000x with ferrite rod  then R increase to > 1M and C reduces to a few hundred pF or less. C is max at 0V then declines with log V. No added series R as this reduces Q with load R = 100x Xc-Xl then Q= 10 BW=10kHz  or 5kHz BW, so Q= 5 to 7 may be optimum for AM BW.

Some varicaps have wider tuning range, but choose C(V=0) from datasheet for desired part.